# VS Code's Terminal keeps returning "Permission Denied"

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, zsh

Per my school's instructions, I'm using VSCode and a bash shell; whenever I try to "run active file in active terminal", it returns "permission denied".

[screenshot of editor and terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sysot.png)

Like I said above, I'm using a **bash** shell - although I just updated from Mac's Sierra to Catalina and am being prompted that the default shell on Mac's OS is now **zsh**. I don't know if maybe that's why the terminal isn't working properly. Before I had updated to Catalina, it was working perfectly! I only recently started classes and I don't even know the difference between bash or zsh or what code editors are great and which are wonky. How do I fix this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina

Comment: `.rb` files are not executable, they need an interpreter to execute them. Pass the `.rb` file as argument to `ruby` (the interpreter).

Comment: thank for answering, folks! β.εηοιτ.βε, I tried doing what the post said but it didn't work. axiac, when I write "ruby [file name].rb", it does work! However, I just started learning TDD and when I try to test something that is meant to return "nil" or "false" or "true", it only returns a blank line?

Comment: @aber : You try to run your Ruby program as bash program. This can't work! I suggest that you add to your program a `!#` line for Ruby, and set the x-bit on the file, so that it is understood as executable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch VS Code in root mode ? Maybe that's the issue? 
So sudo code . in the directory should open it in root mode.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It opened it in root mode and I tried another file with another terminal but it still says Permission Denied :/

Comment: Interesting.. I don't really know what to tell ya. Have you tried running the file by hand ? Calling the ruby command ?

Comment: Yes: I have found that it runs okay except when I'm asking for it to return "nil", "false", or "true" which I'm needing right now for my lessons on TDD.